# Project "Dataflow: Readonly Artifacts (DO NOT DELETE)" visible in my Developers Console

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it correct that I can see the project "***Dataflow: Readonly Artifacts (DO NOT DELETE)***" in my developers console? Ever since I got alpha access to CDF last month, it has been visible.

I also noticed that I got charged on the project even before we started to test and run jobs (which was literally just a few hours ago!). My understanding is that CDF is free in alpha, but that you must pay for any services used e.g. BigQuery, GCS etc. However, I would expect those charges to show up in my other project because I specify that project name/id when actually creating the PipeLine.

[image: Why can I see this project?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those charges are not assessed to you as a Dataflow user -- they are charged to the project owner, which is the Cloud Dataflow team. As part of whitelisting for Dataflow, you've been granted read-only access to the project to allow you to access specific artifacts during Alpha (such as the custom GCE image for Dataflow).